# Creating an editable dropdown in adf without making use of LOV

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an ArrayList and want to show items present in the arraylist inside a adf dropdown component.

This can be achieved with the help of af:selectItem in ADF but the problem here is it wont allow user to enter a new value.

In my case, i want to allow user to enter a value in the box so that i fire an event to update dropdown with the entered value.

I think this can be achieved using af:inputComboBoxListOfValues but problem is that i wont be able to bind it to an array list.

So, can anyone please tell how to achieve my desired functionality in ADF?

---

Rakesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inputComboboxListOfValues 
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/inputComboboxListOfValues.jspx

No need for the ADF Binding as you can see in the components demo - download it here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/documentation/adf-faces-rc-demo-083799.html

Comment: Hi Shay, Thanks a lot for the demo link. It gave an idea of how to bind arraylist to RichInputComboBoxListOfValues.

Comment: Can you share how to bind arraylist? Thanks